# Loadrunner JMS Scripting

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, loadrunner

I have created one LoadRunner JMS script to send a XML message to IBM Websphere Queue, the message reached the Queue and it throws the following error while it processed by IBM BPM consumers

> Error : MQ w exception thrown in header data binding
>
> RFH2Databindings encountered a bad value at
>   com.ibm.ws.sca.mq.data.impl.RFH2databindings.read

Please help me in understanding why this error happened and is there any wrokaround i can do in my scripts

Comment: There are a number of script types that you might use to accomplish this task, from a Java template script to a VB template, C Template, (possibly) Winsock and or Web Services.   Can you clarify which script development model you are using for your JMS virtual user script?

Comment: I have used web services portocol and i have created my own bindings file using the websphere MQ client installed in my scripting machine

Comment: I am using HP vugen 11.52 for scripting

Comment: The issue is solved with the new bidings file created using IBM MQ explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though the client on the scripting machine is a back-level.  The RFH2 headers are no longer used with modern WebSphere MQ versions and have been replaced by Message Properties.  The reason the new .bindings file will have worked would be either that a) it defaults to a setting that does not generate the offending property value; b) the client is capable of generating message properties and the new .bindings file does not enable compatibility; c) the client on the scripting machine has a bug.

If the scripting machine has a full client install, you can use the `dspmqver` command to see which version it is.  If it is not at least WMQ V7.1, it really, desperately, needs an upgrade and preferably to v7.5.  The newest client code (with Fix Packs applied) is at:

- WMQ V7.1 Client is [SupportPacMQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71).
- WMQ V7.5 Client is [SupportPacMQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75). (Strongly preferred.)
- The stand-alone WMQ Explorer is [SupportPac MS0T](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0T).
- The indispensable utilities plugin for WMQ Explorer is [SupportPac MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P).

When installing the WMQ client, install *all* of the features.  If you just grab the jar files the installation is not supported by IBM and you do not get any of the diagnostic utilities.  However, if you feel you really must grab jar files, install the client to a VM or other throw-away machine and grab the jars you need.  Since this is not a supported configuration, there is no documentation about the minimum set of jar files to grab so just get the entire directory.

Comment: @Rob as per your suggestion i checked the version of the MQ client it's version is 6.0.2.11 and the WMQ Exploer that i used to create new binding files(working version) is version 7. As you said the lower version of mq created the RFH2 header issue before.

Comment: @Rob what are the jar files that we need in order to send a meesage to IBM MQ server

Comment: I've updated the question to respond.  Please remember to accept (and maybe also upvote) the question.